# Cannot ping default gateway linux in vmware

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I have a virtual network which is vmnet2 using the `10.0.2.0/24` network, I want my Linux server to be able to ping the default gateway.

I have set the Linux eth1 values to be

```
IPADDR="10.0.2.50"

NETMASK="255.255.255.0"

BOOTPROTO="none"

ONBOOT="yes"

In the etc/sysconfig/network

GATEWAY="10.0.2.1"
```

However, when I attempt to ping `10.0.2.1` the destination host is unreachable. I've restarted the network with **service network restart** but to no avail.

Destination    Gateway     Genmask       Flags    Metric     Ref Use Iface

10.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 U 1 0 0 eth1

default 10.0.2.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 eth1

The first row is the ipaddress and the second is the default gateway

Comment: please show the output from `route`

Comment: @hek2mgl I've put the route

Comment: route on `10.0.2.50` looks ok. has `10.0.2.1` a route to your net defined?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure below,

> Bridge the connection from your desktop .
>   You should be able to ping your Virtual machine IP from the parent machine where you have hosted the same.
>   Make sure you should not have any iptables rules configured that are constraing your connectivity.

This seems to enough , i have made similar setup recently.

Thanks,
Jain

Answer (score 0):

You should add `DEFROUTE=no` in your `eth1` configuration.